# omp single construct with other threads non waiting

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I have some code inside a parallel region, which needs to be executed once. Lets assume, it is the function `single_call()`. Other threads have to wait until `single_call()` is finished. So far, an `omp single` is sufficient.

However I don't need the others threads to wait for this one at the end, and I don't want to enforce all threads executing that code.

This is the one solution I came up with:

```c
bool executed = false;
#pragma omp parallel shared(executed)
{
  // parallel code
#pragma omp critical
  {
    if (!executed)
    {
      single_call();
      executed = true;
    }
  }
  // parallel code, single_call was called once.
}
```

Does anyone has a better solution for this problem? Maybe there is an openmp-builtin?

Comment: It looks like you want a `nowait`. For more flexibility you could also use tasks but a `omp single nowait` seems enough here.

Comment: A `nowait` doesn't cause other threads to wait until `single_call()` is finished.